# Maven dependency org.hibernate.validator 7.0.1.Final with differing dependencies in projects

Tags: maven, hibernate-validator

in two different maven projects, we include the same dependency: `hibernate-validator` `7.0.1.Final` like this:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Running `mvn dependency:list` gives the following results.

**Project A:**

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:7.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
```

Running `mvn dependency:list-repositories` for this project gives:

```
[INFO] Repositories used by this build:
[INFO]        id: sonatype-nexus-snapshots
      url: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => false, update => daily]

[INFO]        id: spy
      url: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]

[INFO]        id: apache.snapshots
      url: http://repository.apache.org/snapshots
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => false, update => daily]

[INFO]        id: apache.snapshots
      url: https://repository.apache.org/snapshots
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => false, update => daily]

[INFO]        id: shibboleth-repo
      url: https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]

[INFO]        id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
```

**Project B:**

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:7.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
```

Running `mvn dependency:list-repositories` for this project gives:

```
[INFO] Repositories Used by this build:
[INFO]       id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]

[INFO]       id: project.local
      url: file:C:\*****\*****/repo
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]

[INFO]       id: apache.snapshots
      url: https://repository.apache.org/snapshots
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => false, update => daily]
```

Until now I thought dependencies of a dependency would be always the same, given that the version is the same, but this result makes me doubt that.

Has this to do with other dependencies in the projects?
Might this be a result of the projects using different repositories?

Comment: First we need to have the full pom files of both projects because the culprit is there... either the project use a different version explicit or have a dependency which uses a different one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies of the org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:7.0.1.Final can be found on [MvnRespository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/7.0.1.Final). Compile Dependencies section of this artifact shows that is uses jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.0 and org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1 (among others).

That means that in project A something actually overrides those transitive dependencies.  You could check the following [link](http://You%20could%20check%20the%20following%20link:%20https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for more information how it is possible. Basically it looks like the project A pom (or the parent pom of this project) declares dependencies towards jakarta.validation-api and jboss-logging which would then be picked by Maven as it searches for "nearest definition" dependencies.